# JVM crashes with Fatal Error

Tags: java, jvm, solaris, fatal-error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0xa) at pc=0xffffffff766c57ac, pid=25341, tid=846885
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode solaris-sparc compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xac57ac]  void Monitor::lock_without_safepoint_check()+0x44
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /rocfm_ipko/deploy/bin/core or core.25341
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000010326a000):  JavaThread "Task 14725376" [_thread_blocked, id=846885, stack(0xffffffff67600000,0xffffffff6763c000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGBUS: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (BUS_ADRALN), si_addr=0x6765744670734d99

Registers:
 G1=0x00000000000000aa G2=0xffffffff771c25ac G3=0xffffffff76d73c60 G4=0x0000000000205c60
 G5=0x0000000000000000 G6=0xffffffff403fe000 G7=0xffffffff66e0da00 Y=0x0000000000000000
 O0=0xffffffff66e0da00 O1=0x0000000000000003 O2=0x0000000000000000 O3=0x0000000000000000
 O4=0xffffffff76ccebf0 O5=0x0000000000160be8 O6=0xffffffff6763a2b1 O7=0xffffffff766c576c
 L0=0x0000000000160800 L1=0x6765744670734c61 L2=0x0000000000000000 L3=0x0000000000000018
 L4=0xffffffff76cd2878 L5=0x0000000000000003 L6=0x007ff000004c8603 L7=0x007fffffffb3706d
 I0=0x0000000100fe7070 I1=0x0000000000164878 I2=0x00000ffffffff66e I3=0xffffffff76b6e000
 I4=0x00000000004a8894 I5=0x0000000000164800 I6=0xffffffff6763a361 I7=0xffffffff767188a0
 PC=0xffffffff766c57ac nPC=0xffffffff766c57b0


Top of Stack: (sp=0xffffffff6763aab0)
0xffffffff6763aab0:   0000000000160800 6765744670734c61
0xffffffff6763aac0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000018
0xffffffff6763aad0:   ffffffff76cd2878 0000000000000003
0xffffffff6763aae0:   007ff000004c8603 007fffffffb3706d
0xffffffff6763aaf0:   0000000100fe7070 0000000000164878
0xffffffff6763ab00:   00000ffffffff66e ffffffff76b6e000
0xffffffff6763ab10:   00000000004a8894 0000000000164800
0xffffffff6763ab20:   ffffffff6763a361 ffffffff767188a0
0xffffffff6763ab30:   000000007fffffff ffffffff5b2eb8c0
0xffffffff6763ab40:   ffffffff5b2eb890 ffffffff5b2ebb80
0xffffffff6763ab50:   ffffffff5b2cdc50 ffffffff40402290
0xffffffff6763ab60:   0000000000000002 00000001014398d0
0xffffffff6763ab70:   ffffffff76ccec00 0000000100fe7070
0xffffffff6763ab80:   ffffffff76d6a948 00000000001ef2b0
0xffffffff6763ab90:   0000000000000001 ffffffff771c2620
0xffffffff6763aba0:   0000000020000000 ffffffff76c5dc68 

Instructions: (pc=0xffffffff766c57ac)
0xffffffff766c578c:   b2 1f 60 78 af 32 30 09 a8 06 c0 19 ac 1d c0 1a
0xffffffff766c579c:   aa 0d a1 ff 93 3d 60 00 a7 2a 70 03 e2 5c c0 14
0xffffffff766c57ac:   e4 5c 61 38 80 a4 80 08 22 60 00 06 92 10 00 11
0xffffffff766c57bc:   40 01 16 49 01 00 00 00 a2 10 00 08 92 10 00 08 

Register to memory mapping:

G1=0x00000000000000aa is an unknown value
G2=0xffffffff771c25ac: __lwp_mutex_trylock+0 in /lib/sparcv9/libc.so.1 at 0xffffffff77100000
G3=0xffffffff76d73c60: _edata+0x2910c in /internaldisk/java/jre1.7.0_80/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so at 0xffffffff75c00000
G4=0x0000000000205c60 is an unknown value
G5=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
G6=0xffffffff403fe000 is an unknown value
G7=0xffffffff66e0da00 is an unknown value

O0=0xffffffff66e0da00 is an unknown value
O1=0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
O2=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
O3=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
O4=0xffffffff76ccebf0: __1cTMaskFillerForNativeG__vtbl_+0x2958 in /internaldisk/java/jre1.7.0_80/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so at 0xffffffff75c00000
O5=0x0000000000160be8 is an unknown value
O6=0xffffffff6763a2b1 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000010326a000
O7=0xffffffff766c576c: JVM_RaiseSignal+0x21a6d4 in /internaldisk/java/jre1.7.0_80/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so at 0xffffffff75c00000

L0=0x0000000000160800 is an unknown value
L1=0x6765744670734c61 is an unknown value
L2=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
L3=0x0000000000000018 is an unknown value
L4=0xffffffff76cd2878: __1cWSystemProcessInterfacePSystemProcessesG__vtbl_+0x1020 in /internaldisk/java/jre1.7.0_80/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so at 0xffffffff75c00000
L5=0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
L6=0x007ff000004c8603 is an unknown value
L7=0x007fffffffb3706d is an unknown value

I0=0x0000000100fe7070 is an unknown value
I1=0x0000000000164878 is an unknown value
I2=0x00000ffffffff66e is an unknown value
I3=0xffffffff76b6e000: _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0 in /internaldisk/java/jre1.7.0_80/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so at 0xffffffff75c00000
I4=0x00000000004a8894 is an unknown value
I5=0x0000000000164800 is an unknown value
I6=0xffffffff6763a361 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000010326a000
I7=0xffffffff767188a0: sysThreadAvailableStackWithSlack+0xcec in /internaldisk/java/jre1.7.0_80/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so at 0xffffffff75c00000


Stack: [0xffffffff67600000,0xffffffff6763c000],  sp=0xffffffff6763aab0,  free space=234k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xac57ac]  void Monitor::lock_without_safepoint_check()+0x44
V  [libjvm.so+0xb188a8]  void Parker::park(bool,long)+0x3f0
V  [libjvm.so+0xc8b370]  Unsafe_Park+0x288
J 2361  sun.misc.Unsafe.park(ZJ)V (0 bytes) @ 0xffffffff703227fc [0xffffffff703226e0+0x11c]
J 2899 C2 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(ZJ)I (171 bytes) @ 0xffffffff6fe10c94 [0xffffffff6fe10c00+0x94]
J 2905 C2 com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.dataload.DataLoadTask.runTask()V (1869 bytes) @ 0xffffffff705912bc [0xffffffff7058eae0+0x27dc]
J 2879 C2 com.subex.nikira.taskcontroller.tasks.rocfmdataload.ROCFMDataLoadTask.runTask()V (2416 bytes) @ 0xffffffff70384900 [0xffffffff703842c0+0x640]
j  com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.AbstractTaskComponent.runTaskWrapper()V+124
j  com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.AbstractTaskComponent.run()V+279
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x2273dc]  void JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*,methodHandle*,JavaCallArguments*,Thread*)+0x2fc
V  [libjvm.so+0x7b40a0]  void JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*,Handle,KlassHandle,Symbol*,Symbol*,Thread*)+0x1b8
V  [libjvm.so+0x2d6064]  void thread_entry(JavaThread*,Thread*)+0x164
V  [libjvm.so+0xc58a64]  void JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0x94
V  [libjvm.so+0x2d1a54]  void JavaThread::run()+0x454
V  [libjvm.so+0xb0ca58]  java_start+0x390

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 2361  sun.misc.Unsafe.park(ZJ)V (0 bytes) @ 0xffffffff7032274c [0xffffffff703226e0+0x6c]
J 2899 C2 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(ZJ)I (171 bytes) @ 0xffffffff6fe10c94 [0xffffffff6fe10c00+0x94]
J 2905 C2 com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.dataload.DataLoadTask.runTask()V (1869 bytes) @ 0xffffffff705912bc [0xffffffff7058eae0+0x27dc]
J 2879 C2 com.subex.nikira.taskcontroller.tasks.rocfmdataload.ROCFMDataLoadTask.runTask()V (2416 bytes) @ 0xffffffff70384900 [0xffffffff703842c0+0x640]
j  com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.AbstractTaskComponent.runTaskWrapper()V+124
j  com.subex.spark.taskcontroller.tasks.AbstractTaskComponent.run()V+279
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000100aa6800 JavaThread "pool-175460-thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=846890, stack(0xffffffff66700000,0xffffffff6673c000)]
  0x00000001019e6800 JavaThread "Task 14725379" [_thread_blocked, id=846889, stack(0xffffffff67300000,0xffffffff6733c000)]
  0x0000000103ebf000 JavaThread "Thread-223827" [_thread_in_native, id=846888, stack(0xffffffff66600000,0xffffffff6663c000)]
  0x0000000102ca9000 JavaThread "process reaper" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=846887, stack(0xffffffff66500000,0xffffffff6653c000)]
  0x0000000103207800 JavaThread "pool-175459-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=846886, stack(0xffffffff65e00000,0xffffffff65e3c000)]
=>0x000000010326a000 JavaThread "Task 14725376" [_thread_blocked, id=846885, stack(0xffffffff67600000,0xffffffff6763c000)]
  0x0000000103350800 JavaThread "Spark Socket" [_thread_in_native, id=29, stack(0xffffffff67800000,0xffffffff6783c000)]
  0x0000000100118000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=2, stack(0xffffffff73800000,0xffffffff7383c000)]
  0x00000001039bd800 JavaThread "Connection To Stream Controller Checker" [_thread_blocked, id=28, stack(0xffffffff67a00000,0xffffffff67a3c000)]
  0x000000010118d800 JavaThread "Spark Server Socket" [_thread_in_native, id=27, stack(0xffffffff67b00000,0xffffffff67b3c000)]
  0x00000001012c1800 JavaThread "Connection timeout timer" [_thread_blocked, id=26, stack(0xffffffff67c00000,0xffffffff67c3c000)]
  0x0000000101873800 JavaThread "License Scheduler" [_thread_blocked, id=25, stack(0xffffffff67d00000,0xffffffff67d3c000)]
  0x000000010333e800 JavaThread "Refresh Manager" [_thread_blocked, id=24, stack(0xffffffff67e00000,0xffffffff67e3c000)]
  0x00000001015cb800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23, stack(0xffffffff67f00000,0xffffffff67f3c000)]
  0x0000000101d2f800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22, stack(0xffffffff68000000,0xffffffff6803c000)]
  0x00000001020f2800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21, stack(0xffffffff68200000,0xffffffff6823c000)]
  0x00000001015d0800 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20, stack(0xffffffff68100000,0xffffffff6813c000)]
  0x00000001002f2000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13, stack(0xffffffff6ab00000,0xffffffff6ab3c000)]
  0x00000001002ef800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12, stack(0xffffffff6ac00000,0xffffffff6ad00000)]
  0x00000001002ed000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11, stack(0xffffffff6ae00000,0xffffffff6af00000)]
  0x00000001002eb000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10, stack(0xffffffff6b000000,0xffffffff6b03c000)]
  0x00000001002c1800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9, stack(0xffffffff6b100000,0xffffffff6b13c000)]
  0x00000001002ba000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8, stack(0xffffffff6b200000,0xffffffff6b23c000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000001002b6000 VMThread [stack: 0xffffffff6b300000,0xffffffff6b400000] [id=7]
  0x0000000100343000 WatcherThread [stack: 0xffffffff6a900000,0xffffffff6aa00000] [id=14]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 33792K, used 14871K [0xffffffff5a800000, 0xffffffff5d800000, 0xffffffff65400000)
  eden space 30720K, 41% used [0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5b46dc28,0xffffffff5c600000)
  from space 3072K, 69% used [0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d418000,0xffffffff5d500000)
  to   space 3072K, 0% used [0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d800000)
 ParOldGen       total 102400K, used 50522K [0xffffffff45400000, 0xffffffff4b800000, 0xffffffff5a800000)
  object space 102400K, 49% used [0xffffffff45400000,0xffffffff48556a50,0xffffffff4b800000)
 PSPermGen       total 77824K, used 71977K [0xffffffff40400000, 0xffffffff45000000, 0xffffffff45400000)
  object space 77824K, 92% used [0xffffffff40400000,0xffffffff44a4a650,0xffffffff45000000)

Card table byte_map: [0xffffffff6f900000,0xffffffff6fa2a000] byte_map_base: 0xff7fffff6fefe000

Polling page: 0xffffffff73600000

Code Cache  [0xffffffff6fc00000, 0xffffffff70600000, 0xffffffff72c00000)
 total_blobs=3075 nmethods=2656 adapters=371 free_code_cache=39167Kb largest_free_block=39867008

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 951208.272 Thread 0x00000001002ed000 2956   !         oracle.net.ano.Ano::init (156 bytes)
Event: 951208.618 Thread 0x00000001002ed000 nmethod 2956 0xffffffff705ed150 code [0xffffffff705ed420, 0xffffffff705edfc8]
Event: 981020.948 Thread 0x00000001002ef800 2957             java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync::tryAcquireShared (177 bytes)
Event: 981023.209 Thread 0x00000001002ef800 nmethod 2957 0xffffffff70480ed0 code [0xffffffff704810e0, 0xffffffff70481828]
Event: 993170.574 Thread 0x00000001002ed000 2958             sun.misc.IOUtils::readFully (138 bytes)
Event: 993170.591 Thread 0x00000001002ed000 nmethod 2958 0xffffffff704515d0 code [0xffffffff70451760, 0xffffffff70451fb0]
Event: 993174.914 Thread 0x00000001002ef800 2959   !         javax.crypto.Cipher::getInstance (248 bytes)
Event: 993174.914 Thread 0x00000001002ed000 2960             java.security.Provider$Service::supportsKeyClass (58 bytes)
Event: 993174.923 Thread 0x00000001002ed000 nmethod 2960 0xffffffff700f2b50 code [0xffffffff700f2ca0, 0xffffffff700f2f70]
Event: 993174.975 Thread 0x00000001002ef800 nmethod 2959 0xffffffff705537d0 code [0xffffffff70553b20, 0xffffffff70554ab8]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 1024450.979 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7751 (full 24):
 PSYoungGen      total 33792K, used 32896K [0xffffffff5a800000, 0xffffffff5d800000, 0xffffffff65400000)
  eden space 30720K, 100% used [0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5c600000,0xffffffff5c600000)
  from space 3072K, 70% used [0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d720000,0xffffffff5d800000)
  to   space 3072K, 0% used [0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d500000)
 ParOldGen       total 102400K, used 49698K [0xffffffff45400000, 0xffffffff4b800000, 0xffffffff5a800000)
  object space 102400K, 48% used [0xffffffff45400000,0xffffffff48488a50,0xffffffff4b800000)
 PSPermGen       total 77824K, used 71977K [0xffffffff40400000, 0xffffffff45000000, 0xffffffff45400000)
  object space 77824K, 92% used [0xffffffff40400000,0xffffffff44a4a650,0xffffffff45000000)
Event: 1024451.017 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7751 (full 24):
 PSYoungGen      total 33792K, used 2336K [0xffffffff5a800000, 0xffffffff5d800000, 0xffffffff65400000)
  eden space 30720K, 0% used [0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5c600000)
  from space 3072K, 76% used [0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d448000,0xffffffff5d500000)
  to   space 3072K, 0% used [0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d800000)
 ParOldGen       total 102400K, used 49858K [0xffffffff45400000, 0xffffffff4b800000, 0xffffffff5a800000)
  object space 102400K, 48% used [0xffffffff45400000,0xffffffff484b0a50,0xffffffff4b800000)
 PSPermGen       total 77824K, used 71977K [0xffffffff40400000, 0xffffffff45000000, 0xffffffff45400000)
  object space 77824K, 92% used [0xffffffff40400000,0xffffffff44a4a650,0xffffffff45000000)
}
Event: 1024994.792 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7752 (full 24):
 PSYoungGen      total 33792K, used 33056K [0xffffffff5a800000, 0xffffffff5d800000, 0xffffffff65400000)
  eden space 30720K, 100% used [0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5c600000,0xffffffff5c600000)
  from space 3072K, 76% used [0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d448000,0xffffffff5d500000)
  to   space 3072K, 0% used [0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d800000)
 ParOldGen       total 102400K, used 49858K [0xffffffff45400000, 0xffffffff4b800000, 0xffffffff5a800000)
  object space 102400K, 48% used [0xffffffff45400000,0xffffffff484b0a50,0xffffffff4b800000)
 PSPermGen       total 77824K, used 71977K [0xffffffff40400000, 0xffffffff45000000, 0xffffffff45400000)
  object space 77824K, 92% used [0xffffffff40400000,0xffffffff44a4a650,0xffffffff45000000)
Event: 1024994.830 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7752 (full 24):
 PSYoungGen      total 33792K, used 2144K [0xffffffff5a800000, 0xffffffff5d800000, 0xffffffff65400000)
  eden space 30720K, 0% used [0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5c600000)
  from space 3072K, 69% used [0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d718000,0xffffffff5d800000)
  to   space 3072K, 0% used [0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d500000)
 ParOldGen       total 102400K, used 50034K [0xffffffff45400000, 0xffffffff4b800000, 0xffffffff5a800000)
  object space 102400K, 48% used [0xffffffff45400000,0xffffffff484dca50,0xffffffff4b800000)
 PSPermGen       total 77824K, used 71977K [0xffffffff40400000, 0xffffffff45000000, 0xffffffff45400000)
  object space 77824K, 92% used [0xffffffff40400000,0xffffffff44a4a650,0xffffffff45000000)
}
Event: 1025062.603 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7753 (full 24):
 PSYoungGen      total 33792K, used 32864K [0xffffffff5a800000, 0xffffffff5d800000, 0xffffffff65400000)
  eden space 30720K, 100% used [0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5c600000,0xffffffff5c600000)
  from space 3072K, 69% used [0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d718000,0xffffffff5d800000)
  to   space 3072K, 0% used [0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d500000)
 ParOldGen       total 102400K, used 50034K [0xffffffff45400000, 0xffffffff4b800000, 0xffffffff5a800000)
  object space 102400K, 48% used [0xffffffff45400000,0xffffffff484dca50,0xffffffff4b800000)
 PSPermGen       total 77824K, used 71977K [0xffffffff40400000, 0xffffffff45000000, 0xffffffff45400000)
  object space 77824K, 92% used [0xffffffff40400000,0xffffffff44a4a650,0xffffffff45000000)
Event: 1025063.160 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7753 (full 24):
 PSYoungGen      total 33792K, used 2288K [0xffffffff5a800000, 0xffffffff5d800000, 0xffffffff65400000)
  eden space 30720K, 0% used [0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5c600000)
  from space 3072K, 74% used [0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d43c030,0xffffffff5d500000)
  to   space 3072K, 0% used [0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d800000)
 ParOldGen       total 102400K, used 50178K [0xffffffff45400000, 0xffffffff4b800000, 0xffffffff5a800000)
  object space 102400K, 49% used [0xffffffff45400000,0xffffffff48500a50,0xffffffff4b800000)
 PSPermGen       total 77824K, used 71977K [0xffffffff40400000, 0xffffffff45000000, 0xffffffff45400000)
  object space 77824K, 92% used [0xffffffff40400000,0xffffffff44a4a650,0xffffffff45000000)
}
Event: 1025118.302 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7754 (full 24):
 PSYoungGen      total 33792K, used 33008K [0xffffffff5a800000, 0xffffffff5d800000, 0xffffffff65400000)
  eden space 30720K, 100% used [0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5c600000,0xffffffff5c600000)
  from space 3072K, 74% used [0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d43c030,0xffffffff5d500000)
  to   space 3072K, 0% used [0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d800000)
 ParOldGen       total 102400K, used 50178K [0xffffffff45400000, 0xffffffff4b800000, 0xffffffff5a800000)
  object space 102400K, 49% used [0xffffffff45400000,0xffffffff48500a50,0xffffffff4b800000)
 PSPermGen       total 77824K, used 71977K [0xffffffff40400000, 0xffffffff45000000, 0xffffffff45400000)
  object space 77824K, 92% used [0xffffffff40400000,0xffffffff44a4a650,0xffffffff45000000)
Event: 1025118.801 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7754 (full 24):
 PSYoungGen      total 33792K, used 2432K [0xffffffff5a800000, 0xffffffff5d800000, 0xffffffff65400000)
  eden space 30720K, 0% used [0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5c600000)
  from space 3072K, 79% used [0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d760020,0xffffffff5d800000)
  to   space 3072K, 0% used [0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d500000)
 ParOldGen       total 102400K, used 50338K [0xffffffff45400000, 0xffffffff4b800000, 0xffffffff5a800000)
  object space 102400K, 49% used [0xffffffff45400000,0xffffffff48528a50,0xffffffff4b800000)
 PSPermGen       total 77824K, used 71977K [0xffffffff40400000, 0xffffffff45000000, 0xffffffff45400000)
  object space 77824K, 92% used [0xffffffff40400000,0xffffffff44a4a650,0xffffffff45000000)
}
Event: 1025394.990 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7755 (full 24):
 PSYoungGen      total 33792K, used 33145K [0xffffffff5a800000, 0xffffffff5d800000, 0xffffffff65400000)
  eden space 30720K, 99% used [0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5c5fe748,0xffffffff5c600000)
  from space 3072K, 79% used [0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d760020,0xffffffff5d800000)
  to   space 3072K, 0% used [0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d500000)
 ParOldGen       total 102400K, used 50338K [0xffffffff45400000, 0xffffffff4b800000, 0xffffffff5a800000)
  object space 102400K, 49% used [0xffffffff45400000,0xffffffff48528a50,0xffffffff4b800000)
 PSPermGen       total 77824K, used 71977K [0xffffffff40400000, 0xffffffff45000000, 0xffffffff45400000)
  object space 77824K, 92% used [0xffffffff40400000,0xffffffff44a4a650,0xffffffff45000000)
Event: 1025395.172 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7755 (full 24):
 PSYoungGen      total 33792K, used 2144K [0xffffffff5a800000, 0xffffffff5d800000, 0xffffffff65400000)
  eden space 30720K, 0% used [0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5a800000,0xffffffff5c600000)
  from space 3072K, 69% used [0xffffffff5d200000,0xffffffff5d418000,0xffffffff5d500000)
  to   space 3072K, 0% used [0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d500000,0xffffffff5d800000)
 ParOldGen       total 102400K, used 50522K [0xffffffff45400000, 0xffffffff4b800000, 0xffffffff5a800000)
  object space 102400K, 49% used [0xffffffff45400000,0xffffffff48556a50,0xffffffff4b800000)
 PSPermGen       total 77824K, used 71977K [0xffffffff40400000, 0xffffffff45000000, 0xffffffff45400000)
  object space 77824K, 92% used [0xffffffff40400000,0xffffffff44a4a650,0xffffffff45000000)
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 337431.048 Thread 0x0000000101d27800 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0xffffffff700ed444 method=net.sf.hibernate.hql.QueryTranslator.generateColumnNames([Lnet/sf/hibernate/type/Type;Lnet/sf/hibernate/engine/SessionFactoryImplementor;)[[Ljava/lang/String; @ 18
Event: 337431.081 Thread 0x0000000101f53800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0xffffffff705812b0 method=net.sf.hibernate.hql.PathExpressionParser.token(Ljava/lang/String;Lnet/sf/hibernate/hql/QueryTranslator;)V @ 268
Event: 337431.683 Thread 0x000000010300a800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0xffffffff705812b0 method=net.sf.hibernate.hql.PathExpressionParser.token(Ljava/lang/String;Lnet/sf/hibernate/hql/QueryTranslator;)V @ 268
Event: 337431.684 Thread 0x000000010300a800 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0xffffffff700ed444 method=net.sf.hibernate.hql.QueryTranslator.generateColumnNames([Lnet/sf/hibernate/type/Type;Lnet/sf/hibernate/engine/SessionFactoryImplementor;)[[Ljava/lang/String; @ 18
Event: 337431.685 Thread 0x000000010300a800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0xffffffff7016f558 method=net.sf.hibernate.hql.QueryTranslator.renderSQL()V @ 182
Event: 337457.686 Thread 0x000000010333e800 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0xffffffff700ed444 method=net.sf.hibernate.hql.QueryTranslator.generateColumnNames([Lnet/sf/hibernate/type/Type;Lnet/sf/hibernate/engine/SessionFactoryImplementor;)[[Ljava/lang/String; @ 18
Event: 446521.515 Thread 0x00000001015d0800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0xffffffff70012ca4 method=java.util.HashMap.removeEntryForKey(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry; @ 85
Event: 580960.015 Thread 0x0000000102bab800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0xffffffff704ab6fc method=org.apache.log4j.helpers.ISO8601DateFormat.format(Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;Ljava/text/FieldPosition;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer; @ 245
Event: 961235.884 Thread 0x000000010326a000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0xffffffff70168a04 method=java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryAcquireShared(I)I @ 36
Event: 961235.884 Thread 0x000000010281c000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0xffffffff70168a04 method=java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryAcquireShared(I)I @ 36

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 613695.294 Thread 0x00000001002c1800 Threw 0xffffffff5a9058b8 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparcv9/jdk7u80/2329/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:743
Event: 613695.294 Thread 0x00000001002c1800 Threw 0xffffffff5a905b40 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparcv9/jdk7u80/2329/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:743
Event: 650027.980 Thread 0x00000001002c1800 Threw 0xffffffff5a8498f8 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparcv9/jdk7u80/2329/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:743
Event: 650027.980 Thread 0x00000001002c1800 Threw 0xffffffff5a849b80 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparcv9/jdk7u80/2329/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:743
Event: 776549.279 Thread 0x00000001002c1800 Threw 0xffffffff5a89d960 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparcv9/jdk7u80/2329/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:743
Event: 776549.279 Thread 0x00000001002c1800 Threw 0xffffffff5a89dbe8 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparcv9/jdk7u80/2329/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:743
Event: 855024.475 Thread 0x00000001002c1800 Threw 0xffffffff5a84b598 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparcv9/jdk7u80/2329/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:743
Event: 855024.475 Thread 0x00000001002c1800 Threw 0xffffffff5a84b820 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparcv9/jdk7u80/2329/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:743
Event: 923197.857 Thread 0x00000001002c1800 Threw 0xffffffff5a914608 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparcv9/jdk7u80/2329/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:743
Event: 923197.857 Thread 0x00000001002c1800 Threw 0xffffffff5a914890 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparcv9/jdk7u80/2329/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:743

Events (10 events):
Event: 1025610.742 Thread 0x000000010326a000 Thread added: 0x000000010326a000
Event: 1025610.774 Thread 0x0000000103207800 Thread added: 0x0000000103207800
Event: 1025610.944 Thread 0x0000000103ebf000 Thread added: 0x0000000103ebf000
Event: 1025610.945 Thread 0x0000000102ca9000 Thread added: 0x0000000102ca9000
Event: 1025613.494 Thread 0x0000000102ca9000 Thread exited: 0x0000000102ca9000
Event: 1025613.497 Thread 0x0000000103ebf000 Thread exited: 0x0000000103ebf000
Event: 1025613.516 Thread 0x0000000103207800 Thread exited: 0x0000000103207800
Event: 1025613.939 Thread 0x000000010326a000 Thread exited: 0x000000010326a000
Event: 1025613.946 Thread 0x000000010326a000 Thread added: 0x000000010326a000
Event: 1025614.131 Thread 0x0000000103207800 Thread added: 0x0000000103207800


Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000100000000  /internaldisk/java/jre1.7.0_80/bin/sparcv9/java
0xffffffff77900000  /usr/lib/sparcv9/libthread.so.1
0xffffffff77600000  /internaldisk/java/jre1.7.0_80/bin/sparcv9/../../lib/sparcv9/jli/libjli.so
0xffffffff77400000  /usr/lib/sparcv9/libdl.so.1
0xffffffff77100000  /usr/lib/sparcv9/libc.so.1
0xffffffff76f00000  /platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1
0xffffffff75c00000  /internaldisk/java/jre1.7.0_80/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so
0xffffffff75800000  /usr/lib/sparcv9/libsocket.so.1
0xffffffff75900000  /usr/lib/sparcv9/libsched.so.1
0xffffffff75500000  /usr/lib/sparcv9/libm.so.1
0xffffffff75200000  /usr/lib/sparcv9/libCrun.so.1
0xffffffff75000000  /usr/lib/sparcv9/libdoor.so.1
0xffffffff74e00000  /usr/lib/sparcv9/libdemangle.so.1
```

JVM is getting crashed with Fatal Exception.This is not frequent.Java process runing on Solaris machine.We are using JDK 1.7.0_80-b15 version.
After going through some articles it seems its bug.If it is really bug please share the version where it is resolved.Some articles are also pointing that if /temp directory is full then this issue happens.But this is not the case here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get a core file from this failure?  If so, post the contents of `pstack core`, where `core` is the name of your core file.

Comment: It is not generating core file.It is only generating error file,the same log i posted here. What can be the reason for that?

Comment: Could you please provide complete crash_logs. You are using 7u80 it is bit older version.

Comment: @saurabh Can you post the output from running `coreadm` from a command-line prompt?  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/coreadm-1m.html  "The `coreadm` command with no arguments reports the current system configuration, for example ..."

Comment: @Fairoz  Can you send me your email address, so that i can send you full error log.

Comment: This appears to be a version of the source code where you're getting your `SIGBUS`: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/hotspot/file/2cd3690f644c/src/share/vm/oops/instanceKlass.cpp#l754  That pretty much has to be from a load instruction getting a misaligned address somewhere.

Comment: @Fairoz I have mailed you full log.Also i have shared log here but because of word limitation some part is cut cut off.

Comment: After analyzing the logs, issue looks more similar to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151336 which has fix in JDK9

Comment: @Fairoz May be this is bug in JDK 7.But this issue only comes in Solaris machine.

Comment: @saurabh It's pretty hard to generate a `SIGBUS` on any x86 machine. It's *really* easy to generate a `SIGBUS` on any SPARC machine - and almost all SPARC machines run Solaris.